# T-SQL column derived by two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Suppose to have this query:

```
SELECT ((ColumnA*ColumnB)/ColumnC) AS ColDerA
       ,(ColumnD + ColumnE - ColumnF) AS ColDerB
       ,(ColDerA - ColDerB) AS ColDerC
FROM TableA
```

When I write `(ColDerA - ColDerB) AS ColDerC` SQL return this error:
`Invalid column name 'ColDerA'` (same for `ColDerB`).
How do I create `ColDerC` column?

Thanks.

Comment: SQL does not execute a query in a drop through manner. You should look up sql server order of execution. In this case coldera and colderb are not visible for the third row of your query. You could simply repeat the calculations for these variables to calculate colderc.

Comment: All expressions in a `SELECT` clause are evaluated "as if" they're all being computed in parallel. Not left-to-right or anything else. Which is why the expressions cannot depend on each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a nested query

```
SELECT ColDerA, ColDerB, (ColDerA - ColDerB) AS ColDerC
FROM
(
   SELECT ((ColumnA*ColumnB)/ColumnC) AS ColDerA
        ,(ColumnD + ColumnE - ColumnF) AS ColDerB
  FROM TableA
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that SQL doesn't work in ordinary fashion, from top to bottom (as you read the code), so for user it might be obvious that after naming columns with aliases, the aliases can be used in the same query. Unfortunately not, SQL first executes the query as a batch, so in order to use any results that the query returned, you need to wrap it in subquery (nested query). Therefore, you have to use it like this:

```
SELECT ColDerA, ColDerB, ColDerA - ColDerB FROM (
SELECT ((ColumnA*ColumnB)/ColumnC) AS ColDerA
   ,(ColumnD + ColumnE - ColumnF) AS ColDerB
   --,(ColDerA - ColDerB) AS ColDerC --this would work, if you had used directly columns from the table: ((ColumnA*ColumnB)/ColumnC) - (ColumnD + ColumnE - ColumnF)
FROM TableA ) AS A
```